# CoffeeScript For NetBeans 8.0 Plugin: Set Target Folder For Compiles JS

Tags: netbeans, coffeescript, netbeans-7, netbeans-platform

I am using this Plugin for NetBeans [CoffeeScript For NetBeans](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/39007/coffeescript-netbeans) to compile my CoffeeScript File to JS.

For the project I have this folder.

http://prntscr.com/7euyfe

The coffee file will go to the app/coffee and the compiled goes to app/js.

What I want is, when I compile the File, it will go to the /app/js folder. But as it stands, it only dumps the file on the same folder where the coffee file is.

There is a setting in the Tools > Options, where I can set the target directory as seen in the screenshot.

http://prntscr.com/7euyur

But when I set it, the compiled result became like this.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/2SLQH3B.png]

Is there anyone who use NetBeans know how to do set this up?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Grunt/Gulp to compile coffescript instead of the plugin. Set watcher ([grunt-contrib-watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch)) to watch your coffee scripts files and set the watcher to execute [grunt-contrib-coffee](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-coffee) task upon file save.